# Can I set a member variable before constructor call?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11

I started to implement an ID based memory pool, where every element has an id, which is basically an index in a vector. In this special case I know the index before I construct the object itself so I thought I set the ID before I call the constructor.

### Some details

Allocating an object from an ID based pool is the following:

1. allocate a free id from the pool
2. get a memory address based on the id value
3. construct the object on the memory address
4. set the ID member of the object

and the deallocation is based on that id

here is the code (thanks jrok):

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
  X()
  {
    // id come from "nothing"
    std::cout << "X constructed with id: " << id << std::endl;
  }
  int id;
};

int main()
{
    void* buf = operator new(sizeof(X));

    // can I set the ID before the constructor call
    ((X*)buf)->id = 42;
    new (buf) X;
    std::cout << ((X*)buf)->id;
}
```

### EDIT

I found a stock solution for this in boost sandbox:
[sandbox Boost.Tokenmap](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/tokenmap/libs/tokenmap/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: That's a lot of code; can you pinpoint the section that is relevant to your question?

Comment: I put two comment in the code, maybe I should mark it somehow

Comment: I suggest you remove all the code that isn't directly relevant to the question, and construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates what you're talking about ;)

Comment: Should I remove more code parts?

Comment: If you're asking if you can do [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8740169426608b4), then the answer is no (even though it works :)).

Comment: Use the appropiate data structures for the appropiate problem. For this (id based access thing) use a hashtable (`std::unordered_map`). Your ids are indices of the objects in the array. What happens if I remove an element? Wou have to update all the IDs. Again, use a map

Comment: I think this is faster. I use std::unique_ptr for remove with a custom deleter

Comment: @jrok: thanks, I ask that! ;-)

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant: The new code makes your question 100x clearer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you're doing, but it's really not a good idea. According to the standard, your code invokes [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

> #### 3.8 Object lifetime [basic.life]
>
> The lifetime of an object is a runtime property of the object. **An object is said to have non-trivial initialization
>   if it is of a class or aggregate type and it or one of its members is initialized by a constructor other than a trivial
>   default constructor**. [ Note: initialization by a trivial copy/move constructor is non-trivial initialization. —
>   end note ] **The lifetime of an object of type T begins when:**
>
> — **storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and**
>
> — **if the object has non-trivial initialization, its initialization is complete**.
>
> The lifetime of an object of type T ends when:
>
> — if T is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or
>
> — the storage which the object occupies is reused or released.
>
> **Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been
>   allocated** or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is
>   reused or released, **any pointer that refers to the storage location where the object will be or was located
>   may be used but only in limited ways**. For an object under construction or destruction, see 12.7. Otherwise,
>   such a pointer refers to allocated storage (3.7.4.2), and using the pointer as if the pointer were of type void*,
>   is well-defined. Such a pointer may be dereferenced but the resulting lvalue may only be used in limited
>   ways, as described below. **The program has undefined behavior if:**
>
> — **the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the
>   object**

When your code invokes Undefined Behaviour, the implementation is allowed to do anything it wants to. In most cases nothing will happen - and if you're lucky your compiler will warn you - but occasionally the result will be unexpectedly catastrophic.

You describe a pool of N objects of the same type, using a contiguous array as the underlying storage. Note that in this scenario you do not need to store an integer ID for each allocated object - if you have a pointer to the allocated object, you can derive the ID from the offset of the object within the array like so:

```
struct Object
{
};

const int COUNT = 5; // allow enough storage for COUNT objects

char storage[sizeof(Object) * COUNT];

// interpret the storage as an array of Object
Object* pool = static_cast<Object*>(static_cast<void*>(storage));

Object* p = pool + 3; // get a pointer to the third slot in the pool
int id = p - pool; // find the ID '3' for the third slot
```

Comment: Really? I do not access that member but set it and access it in object life time. Or not? Or nullifying the memory (for ex. calloc) before constructor call is also UD?

Comment: In standardese, "access" means anything involving a class-member-access using the `.` or `->` syntax. Functions like `calloc`, `memset` do not perform a class-member-access, in which case this rule does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I set a member variable before constructor call?

No, but you can make a base class with ID that sets ID within its constructor (and throws exception if ID can't be allocated, for example). Derive from that class, and at the moment derived class enter constructor, ID will be already set. You could also manage id generation within another class - either within some kind of global singleton, or you could pass id manager as a first parameter to constructor.

```
typedef int Id;
class IdObject{
public:
    Id getId() const{
        return id;
    }
protected:
    IdManager* getIdManager() ...
    IdObject()
    :id(0){
        IdManager* manager = getIdManager();
        id = manager->generateId();
        if (!id)
            throw IdException;
        manager->registerId(id, this);           
    }
    ~IdObject(){
        if (id)
            getIdManager()->unregisterId(id, this);
    }       
private:
    Id id;
    IdObject& operator=(IdObject &other){
    }
    IdObject(IdObject &other)
    :id(0){
    }
};

class DerivedObject: public IdObject{
public:
    DerivedObject(){
        //at this point, id is set.
    }
};
```

This kind of thing.

Comment: So I use the ID for memory allocation/deallocation. So I get the DerivedObject from the pool based on the ID, which is an index (after multiply with sizeof(DerivedObject) ) in a std::vector<char>.

Comment: @Industrial-antidepressant: Is this a question or a comment? I don't see a problem so far.

Comment: This is waaay overcomplicating things. There's no need to even store an ID - it can be derived from the object's offset within the underlying storage.

Comment: @willj: he wants id, I told him how to add ID. Of course it is simpler to FIRST allocate the memory, and then assign ID, but that's another story. "it can be derived" Only if you have a pool that can't grow. If your pool has to grow, you won't be able to just reallocate entire pool (in C++03, at least) because it'll destroy all objects that are already allocated. So you'll end up allocating it in chunks. And with chunks, you can't calculate offsets.

Comment: Could you please s/Manager/Registry/?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: No, because "Registry" normally means "Windows Registry" or "Program settings database". Which doesn't correctly describe functionality of this class.

Comment: In that case, maybe s/registerID/manageID/ and s/unregisterID/unmanageID/. (P.S.: I'm being facetious)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: "manageID" implies that class does something with it in addition to just "remembering it". Anyway, it is matter of taste. It would make sense to rename "Manager" into "Pool". However, it is not a pool in the example because its functionality is unknown. You could also call it "IdRegistrator", but only if registering IDs is the only thing it does. It is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot set anything in an object before its constructor is called.  However, you have a couple of choices:

1. Pass the ID to the constructor itself, so it can store the ID in the object.
2. Allocate extra memory in front of the object being constructed, store the ID in that extra memory, then have the object access that memory when needed.

Comment: But why? In the constructor I don't touch the "ID" member.

Comment: But does the object need to know its ID during its lifetime? If yes, then passing the ID in the constructor makes sense. Even if the constructor itself does not use the ID, it can still initialize the ID for use. But if the object does not need to know the ID, then there is no point in storing the ID in the object at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the object's to-be address, which is the case for your scenario, then yes you can do that kind of thing. However, it is not well-defined behaviour, so it's most probably *not a good idea* (and in every case not good design). Although it will probably "work fine".

Using a `std::map` as suggested in a comment above is cleaner and has no "ifs" and "whens" of UB attached.

Despite writing to a known memory address will probably be "working fine", an object doesn't exist before the constructor is run, so using any of its members is bad mojo.
Anything is possible. No compiler will likely do any such thing, but the compiler might for example memset the object's storage with zero before running the constructor, so even if you don't set your ID field, it's still overwritten. You have no way of knowing, since what you're doing is undefined.

Comment: So a constructor can modify the object's memory region before the call? Is this in the standard?

Comment: No, the constructor modifies the object's memory either immediately before the code inside its curly brackets is run (if you specify an initializer list), or _while it runs_ (the constructor code you write). However, _you_ can still modify an object's memory before the constructor is run if you know the address -- it just isn't _defined behaviour_, so it's technically "wrong" to do it. Anything is possible, it may work or not. Nothing in the standard prohibits a compiler from doing something else in addition (think of a debug build, e.g. filling memory with special patterns).

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you want to do this before the constructor call?

> Allocating an object from an ID based pool is the following:
>
> ```
> 1) allocate a free id from the pool
> 2) get a memory address based on the id value
> 3) construct the object on the memory address
> 4) set the ID member of the object and the deallocation is based on that id
> ```

According to your steps, you are setting the ID after the constructor.

> so I thought I set the ID before I call the constructor.

I hate to be blunt, but you need to have a better reason than that to wade into the undefined behaviour territory. Remember, as programmers, there is a lot we're learning all the time and unless there is absolutely no way around it, we need to stay away from minefields, undefined behavior being one of them.

As other people have pointed out, yes you can do it, but that's like saying you can do `rm -rf /` as root. Doesn't mean you should :)

> C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot. C++ makes it harder, but when you do, you blow away your whole leg! — Bjarne Stroustrup

Comment: Yes, I want to print out the ID in the object's constructor.

Comment: So pass in the ID as a constructor parameter. It doesn't even need to be a member variable. Why would a class want to know the details of where it is allocated?